# ICommand MVVM implementation

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, icommand

So in this particular MVVM implementation I'm doing, I need several commands. I really got tired of implementing the ICommand classes one by one, so I came up with a solution, but I don't know how good it is, so the input of any WPF expert here will be greatly appreciated. And if you could provide a better solution, even better.

What I did is a single ICommand class and two delegates which take an object as a parameter, one delegate is void (for OnExecute), the other bool (for OnCanExecute). So in the constructor of my ICommand (which is called by the ViewModel class) I send the two methods, and on each ICommand method I invoke the delegates' methods.

It works really good, but I'm not sure if this is a bad way to do it, or if there's a better way. Below is the complete code, any input will be greatly appreciated, even negative, but please be constructive.

ViewModel:

```
public class TestViewModel : DependencyObject
{
    public ICommand Command1 { get; set; }
    public ICommand Command2 { get; set; }
    public ICommand Command3 { get; set; }

    public TestViewModel()
    {
        this.Command1 = new TestCommand(ExecuteCommand1, CanExecuteCommand1);
        this.Command2 = new TestCommand(ExecuteCommand2, CanExecuteCommand2);
        this.Command3 = new TestCommand(ExecuteCommand3, CanExecuteCommand3);
    }

    public bool CanExecuteCommand1(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void ExecuteCommand1(object parameter)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Executing command 1");
    }

    public bool CanExecuteCommand2(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void ExecuteCommand2(object parameter)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Executing command 2");
    }

    public bool CanExecuteCommand3(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void ExecuteCommand3(object parameter)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Executing command 3");
    }
}
```

ICommand:

```
public class TestCommand : ICommand
{
    public delegate void ICommandOnExecute(object parameter);
    public delegate bool ICommandOnCanExecute(object parameter);

    private ICommandOnExecute _execute;
    private ICommandOnCanExecute _canExecute;

    public TestCommand(ICommandOnExecute onExecuteMethod, ICommandOnCanExecute onCanExecuteMethod)
    {
        _execute = onExecuteMethod;
        _canExecute = onCanExecuteMethod;
    }

    #region ICommand Members

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute.Invoke(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute.Invoke(parameter);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Check out Karl Shifflet's implementation of RelayCommand: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/ExploringWPFMVVM.aspx

Answer (score 95, accepted):

This is almost identical to how [Karl Shifflet demonstrated](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32101/Exploring-a-Model-View-ViewModel-Application-WPF-P) a `RelayCommand`, where `Execute` fires a predetermined `Action<T>`. A top-notch solution, if you ask me.

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;

    public RelayCommand(Predicate<object> canExecute, Action<object> execute)
    {
        _canExecute = canExecute;
        _execute = execute;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add => CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        remove => CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }
}
```

This could then be used as...

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    private ICommand _doSomething;
    public ICommand DoSomethingCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_doSomething == null)
            {
                _doSomething = new RelayCommand(
                    p => this.CanDoSomething,
                    p => this.DoSomeImportantMethod());
            }
            return _doSomething;
        }
    }
}
```

Read more:
[Josh Smith (introducer of `RelayCommand`): Patterns - WPF Apps With The MVVM Design Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)

Comment: It does look similar to mine. It'd be interesting to know the pros and cons of using this. Do you have a link to the article or blog where you read this?

Comment: I'm usins this approach since I'm working with MVVM and it works like a charm ;)

Comment: im using it as well, the only con i can find is that you dont have a keyboard shortcut assigned to the command. any ideas?

Comment: @Aran The best solution I've found for assigning keyboard shortcuts to a RelayCommand is CommandReference.  The only con to it is that you don't get the auto population of the shortcut in context menus and such.  http://joyfulwpf.blogspot.com/2009/05/mvvm-commandreference-and-keybinding.html

Comment: I dont understand how will this.DoSomeImportantMethod would get a command parameter

Comment: Shouldn't the implementation be changed to if (_doSomething != null) of did I misunderstand something?

Comment: @quest4truth No, it's correctly implementing lazy initialization-- it instantiates `_doSomething` if it hasn't already been instantiated.

Comment: Those articles are amazing, thank you for those links.

Comment: The Josh Smith link is broken since 22nd Jan 2021. :(

Answer (score 18):

I have written this [article](http://vladimir-kurka.blogspot.com/2010/11/implementation-of-icommand-interface.html) about the ICommand interface.

The idea - creating a universal command that takes two delegates: one is called when `ICommand.Execute (object param)` is invoked, the second checks the status of whether you can execute the command `(ICommand.CanExecute (object param))`.

Requires the method to switching event `CanExecuteChanged`. It is called from the user interface elements for switching the state `CanExecute()` command.

```
public class ModelCommand : ICommand
{
    #region Constructors

    public ModelCommand(Action<object> execute)
        : this(execute, null) { }

    public ModelCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    #endregion

    #region ICommand Members

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute != null ? _canExecute(parameter) : true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        if (_execute != null)
            _execute(parameter);
    }

    public void OnCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    #endregion

    private readonly Action<object> _execute = null;
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute = null;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I've just created a little [example](http://www.treukhov.com/commandadapter.zip) showing how to implement commands in convention over configuration style. However it requires Reflection.Emit() to be available. The supporting code may seem a little weird but once written it can be used many times.

Teaser:

```
public class SampleViewModel: BaseViewModelStub
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [UiCommand]
    public void HelloWorld()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello World!");
    }

    [UiCommand]
    public void Print()
    {
        MessageBox.Show(String.Concat("Hello, ", Name, "!"), "SampleViewModel");
    }

    public bool CanPrint()
    {
        return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Name);
    }
}
```

}

**UPDATE**: now there seem to exist some libraries like http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/101881/Executing-Command-Logic-in-a-View-Model that solve the problem of ICommand boilerplate code.

Answer (score 6):

@Carlo I really like your implementation of this, but I wanted to share my version and how to use it in my ViewModel

First implement ICommand

```
public class Command : ICommand
{
    public delegate void ICommandOnExecute();
    public delegate bool ICommandOnCanExecute();

    private ICommandOnExecute _execute;
    private ICommandOnCanExecute _canExecute;

    public Command(ICommandOnExecute onExecuteMethod, ICommandOnCanExecute onCanExecuteMethod = null)
    {
        _execute = onExecuteMethod;
        _canExecute = onCanExecuteMethod;
    }

    #region ICommand Members

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute?.Invoke() ?? true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute?.Invoke();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Notice I have removed the parameter from **ICommandOnExecute** and **ICommandOnCanExecute** and added a null to the constructor

Then to use in the ViewModel

```
public Command CommandToRun_WithCheck
{
    get
    {
        return new Command(() =>
        {
            // Code to run
        }, () =>
        {
            // Code to check to see if we can run 
            // Return true or false
        });
    }
}

public Command CommandToRun_NoCheck
{
    get
    {
        return new Command(() =>
        {
            // Code to run
        });
    }
}
```

I just find this way cleaner as I don't need to assign variables and then instantiate, it all done in one go.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! It's definitely interesting to see other ways to solve this. Ever since I read about the RelayCommand, I decided to adopt that pattern. I haven't done WPF in YEARS, but I definitely used the RelayCommand for a few years before the trend in my company shifted to web.