# Enable Disable Button base on validation in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, validation

I have a WPF Form, that has a text box and a button. I am validating the text box to have only characters. Validation works fine, But I need to disable the button if there are validation error and enable them if there are no validation errors. 
Below is my code:

```
<TextBox Name="tbProductName" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="4,9,0,0" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="213" 
                    Text="{Binding Path = ProductCode, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,NotifyOnValidationError=True}">               
            <Validation.ErrorTemplate>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="textBox"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding [0].ErrorContent}" Foreground="Red"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Validation.ErrorTemplate>
        </TextBox>
        <Button Name ="btnDownload" Content="Download" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="87" Height="24" Click="btnDownload_Click"/>


public class ViewModel: System.ComponentModel.INotifyDataErrorInfo 
   {
       private readonly Dictionary<string, ICollection<string>> _validationErrors = new Dictionary<string, ICollection<string>>();
       private readonly Model _productCode = new Model();
       public string ProductCode
       {
           get { return _productCode.ProductCode; }
           set
           {
               _productCode.ProductCode = value;
               ValidateModelProperty(value, "ProductCode");
           }
       }

       protected void ValidateModelProperty(object value, string propertyName)
       {
           if (_validationErrors.ContainsKey(propertyName))
               _validationErrors.Remove(propertyName);

           PropertyInfo propertyInfo = _productCode.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
           IList<string> validationErrors =
                 (from validationAttribute in propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<ValidationAttribute>()
                  where !validationAttribute.IsValid(value)
                  select validationAttribute.FormatErrorMessage(string.Empty))
                  .ToList();

           _validationErrors.Add(propertyName, validationErrors);
           RaiseErrorsChanged(propertyName);
       }
         /* Raise the ErrorsChanged for all properties explicitly */

       protected void ValidateModel()
       {
           _validationErrors.Clear();
           ICollection<ValidationResult> validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
           ValidationContext validationContext = new ValidationContext(_productCode, null, null);
           if (!Validator.TryValidateObject(_productCode, validationContext, validationResults, true))
           {
               foreach (ValidationResult validationResult in validationResults)
               {
                   string property = validationResult.MemberNames.ElementAt(0);
                   if (_validationErrors.ContainsKey(property))
                   {
                       _validationErrors[property].Add(validationResult.ErrorMessage);
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       _validationErrors.Add(property, new List<string> { validationResult.ErrorMessage });
                   }
               }
           }

           /* Raise the ErrorsChanged for all properties explicitly */
           RaiseErrorsChanged("ProductCode");
       }

       #region INotifyDataErrorInfo members
       public event EventHandler<System.ComponentModel.DataErrorsChangedEventArgs> ErrorsChanged;
       private void RaiseErrorsChanged(string propertyName)
       {
           if (ErrorsChanged != null)
               ErrorsChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.DataErrorsChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
       }

       public System.Collections.IEnumerable GetErrors(string propertyName)
       {
           if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName)
               || !_validationErrors.ContainsKey(propertyName))
               return null;

           return _validationErrors[propertyName];
       }

       public bool HasErrors
       {
           get { return _validationErrors.Count > 0; }
       }
       #endregion

    }  

public class Model
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must enter a product code to download.")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]+$", ErrorMessage = "The Product Code must only contain letters (a-z, A-Z).")]
        public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    }
```

How can I set the isEnabled property of the button to Validation.HasErrors?

Comment: `IsEnabled="{Binding Path= BtnIsEnabled}` ?!

Comment: as above or look into Binding to a ICommand implementation search here or maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468791/wpf-icommand-mvvm-implementation

Answer (score 2):

Ideally your button would bind it's "Command" property to a public [ICommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) viewmodel property.

The CanExecute method would be evaluated, returning true or false. The button would be enabled/disabled accordingly.

You can read more about ICommand, along with an implementation of the interface [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn237302.aspx).

Below are the changes required, assuming your using the [RelayCommand (See Fig. 3)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090030) implementation described in the aforementioned article.

**Register the command**

```
private readonly ICommand _downloadCommand = new RelayCommand(OnDownload, CanDownload);
```

**Used for binding:**

```
public ICommand DownloadCommand { get { return _downloadCommand; } }
```

**Methods to invoke when the command is executed:**

```
private void OnDownload(object parameter) { ... Do your download code here ... }
private bool CanDownload(object parameter) { return HasErrors == false; }
```

**Update your XAML binding:**

```
<Button Content="Download" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="87" Height="24" Command="{Binding DownloadCommand}" />
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. I amy be missing something but I am getting the error
The best overloaded method match for 'RelayCommand.RelayCommand(System.Action<object>, System.Predicate<object>)' has some invalid arguments

cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.Predicate<object>'

Comment: Imeplementation of relay command:
public class RelayCommand : ICommand { #region Fields readonly Action<object> _execute; readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute; #endregion // Fields #region Constructors public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute) : this(execute, null) { } public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute) { if (execute == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("execute"); _execute = execute; _canExecute = canExecute; } #endregion // Constructors #region ICommand Members [DebuggerStepThrough] public bool CanExecute(object parameter) { return _canExecute =

Comment: I've updated my answer.  I added 'object parameter' to the OnDownload and CanDownload methods.

Answer (score 1):

I would say use the same technique for the `Binding` you used for the rest of your code!!

In your `xaml`

```
<Button Name ="btnDownload"  IsEnabled="{Binding Path= BtnIsEnabled} click="btnDownload_Click"/>
```

In your code

```
    public bool BtnIsEnabled
    {
        get { return this._BtnIsEnabled; }
        set
        {
            this._BtnIsEnabled = value;
            base.OnPropertyChanged("BtnIsEnabled");
        }
    }
    private bool _BtnIsEnabled;
```

and then where ever you want to disable your `Button` go something like

```
BtnIsEnabled = Validation.HasErrors ? false : true ;
```

Obviously this is a pseudo scribble. Unless you're after something very specific that I can't seem to find out. Seems you used binding in your code already and I would guess you know how to.