# WPF Button Template issue

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to make a reuseable button that has a Text followed by an X button (kind of like the close tab button on Google Chrome).  I figured to do it something like this;

```
<Style x:Key="TestButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Margin ="3,5,3,5" BorderBrush="Black"  Grid.Column="0" />
                <Button Background="White" BorderBrush="White" Content="X" Grid.Column="1" />
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource TestButtonStyle}" Content="Testing" Padding="5" Margin="5"  />
```

The problem with this is that `Button` Click command works for the `Label` as well as the `X Button`.  If I put the click command into the Style then every button will have the same click command.  What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `TemplateBinding` on button to inherit Command from parent template button.

```
<Button Background="White" BorderBrush="White" Content="X"
        Grid.Column="1" Command="{TemplateBinding Command}" />
```

This way you can set different commands on multiple buttons and re-use the same style:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource TestButtonStyle}" Content="Testing"
        Padding="5" Margin="5" Command="{Binding TestCommand}"/>
```

Comment: Sorry to ask stupid questions but would would the code for "TestCommand" be like?

Comment: Have you read about ICommand and MVVM pattern? If not this link [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468791/wpf-icommand-mvvm-implementation) will help you understand it. Also google for it you will get tons of articles over net.