# DataTemplate button command from binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button, datatemplate

I'm using Wpf and I'm passing a `List<Value>` to a `<ItemsControl>` in the xaml. I would like to bind the `string` in the `Value` Object to the Command of a Button. This xaml part looks like this:

```
    <Grid Margin="0,0,2,0">
    <Grid Margin="10">
        <ItemsControl Name="details">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,5">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            ....
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        ...
                        <Button Grid.Column="2"
                                Content="{Binding ButtonContent}"
                                Visibility="{Binding ButtonVisibility}"
                                Command="{Binding ButtonClickMethod}" />
        ...
```

My `Value` Class looks like this:

```
public class Value
{        
    ...
    public string ButtonClickMethod { get; set; }

}
```

I'm setting the string link this:

```
v.ButtonClickMethod = "RelatedActivityId_OnClick";
```

And the Method is in the same class and looks like this:

```
private void RelatedActivityId_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("RelatedActivityId_OnClick");
    }
```

Everything besides this is working properly and unses the same Object for the binding.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So the string `ButtonClickMethod` contains the name of the method to execute?

Comment: Yes I've just added some more code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Command` property of the Button is of type `ICommand` so you cannot bind it to a `string` value.

You need to update your `ButtonClickMethod` to be of type ICommand or create a new property to bind you `Command` to.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468791/wpf-icommand-mvvm-implementation) answer for a sample implementation of ICommand.

If you need the button to execute code based on a parameter (string value?) then you can use the `CommandParameter` property, then use that paramters in your Command handler.

```
public class Value
{        
    public Value()
    {
        ButtonCommand  = new RelayCommand((a) => true, CommandMethod); 
    }

    public RelayCommand ButtonCommand {get; set; }
    public string ButtonClickMethod { get; set; }

    private void CommandMethod(object obj)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(obj?.ToString());
    }
}
```

and the XAML:

```
<Button Grid.Column="2"
         Content="{Binding ButtonContent}"
         Visibility="{Binding ButtonVisibility}"
         Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}"
         CommandParameter="{Binding ButtonClickMethod}" />
```

Comment: (If the goal is the execution based on a dynamically set value then just assigning a different command is way easier than using strings and reflection anyway.)

Comment: i'm hoping he can use the parameter to decide which method to call rather than find it though reflection... assuming there is a finite amount of methods that he can call into.

Answer (score 1):

The Button.Command property binds only to objects which implement the ICommand interface.
If you want to invoke a method which its name is ButtonClickMethod, you will have to:

1. Create a class which implements ICommand interface.
2. Create a object of that class and bind it to your button (bind it to Button.Command).
3. Pass the Value.ButtonClickMethod as a CommandParameter to your ICommand object.
4. Use this to invoke any method you would like to.