# Efficient use of the ICommand interface

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, xamarin

I'm beginning a project using Xamarin Forms for cross-platform development of a mobile app. I'm using the MVVM model, of which I have little experience of beyond a few small WPF applications.

I'm using the ICommand interface to create commands and binding to them in the view's XAML, which by default involves a good amount of duplicate code. Xamarin.Forms provides a concrete subtype, Command, of ICommand, which is used as in the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468791/wpf-icommand-mvvm-implementation), and I see two obvious ways to instantiate them.

Option #1 - Assign the Commands in the constructor.

```
public class Presenter : ObservableObject
{
    public Presenter()
    {
        DoStuffCommand = new Command(DoStuff);
    }

    public ICommand DoStuffCommand { get; set; }

    private void DoStuff()
    {
        // VM stuff
    }

}
```

Option #2 - Instantiate Command in the getter

```
public class Presenter : ObservableObject
{
    public ICommand RunCommand { get { return new Command(DoStuff); } }

    private void DoStuff()
    {
        // VM stuff
    }

}
```

Many view models are going to have a number of commands, and approach #2 avoids assigning all of these one by one in the constructor - when the commands action is not going to change, it's clearer to me having this action declared with the ICommand itself. On the other hand, this will create a new instance of Command every time the command fires, which is clearly less efficient memory wise than approach #1.

Does anyone have experience of this, and/or could give me an idea of whether this could impact performance noticeably? And is there a way to improve upon this, such as by manually destroying the Command objects?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative to option #2 would be to have a backing field for it and  ensures it only instantiates once:

```
private ICommand _doStuffCommand;
public ICommand DoStuffCommand =>
    _doStuffCommand = _doStuffCommand ?? new Command(DoStuff);

private void DoStuff()
{

}
```

Comment: That's great, thanks - exactly what I was looking for. Surprised I haven't seen this pattern used more often.

Comment: Yes, it is quite simple really :)