# WPF button command in view not firing to ICommand in viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am developing my first app using MVVM and I am stuck with my command button.

In my view I have:

```
<Button x:Name="btSave" Command="{Binding AddContactCommand}" Content="Save" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="183,186,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
```

In the code behind i have:

```
public partial class ContactView : Window
{
    private ContactViewModel contactVM;

    public ContactView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        contactVM = new ContactViewModel();
        this.DataContext = contactVM;
    }
}
```

In the view model I have:

```
public ICommand AddContactCommand { get; private set; }

void AddContact()
{
    ContactData ContactData = new ContactData();
    bSaved = ContactData.SaveContact("Theresa","Theresa","Theresa","Theresa");      
}
```

the `AddContact()` in the view model never gets fired.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What `AddContact()` method has to do with `AddContactCommand` ? Where do you instantiate property (`AddContactCommand =  new Something()`)? See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1468830/1997232) for an example of `ICommand`.

Comment: Just because you *name* the method `AddContact` and the Command `AddContactCommand` doesn't mean they are in any way related, as far as your program is concerned at least. You are missing something like this in your code: `AddContactCommand = new ClassThatImplementsICommand(AddContact)` If you don't have an ICommand implementation, google for `RelayCommand`, it's a simple implementation, that covers the basics.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.  I have resolved it now using the RelayCommand as suugested.

Answer (score 0):

Check your DataContext as I assume that is the issue.

If your ViewModel is in the code behind in the Constructor put the following:

```
DataContext = this;
```

Otherwise if it's another class you need to do the same thing but do:

```
DataContext = new MyViewModel();
```

At least I assume this is your issue from what you have posted.