# WPF ICommand Implementation for ComboBoxItem

Tags: wpf, combobox, icommand, relaycommand

How can I implement ICommand in WPF(4.5) ComboBoxItem? I tried CommandBinding but I getting error message "Command' property of type 'CommandBinding'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject"

Comment: Please post your code - what property on ComboBoxItem are you trying to bind to ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF ICommand MVVM implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468791/wpf-icommand-mvvm-implementation)

Comment: Command is used to handle user input from buttons (mostly) If you want to have something(?) execute when selecting a item in a `ComboBox` I suggest either fire an event or use databinding.

Comment: <ComboBox Width="200" ItemsSource="{Binding ModelList}" IsEditable="True" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedModelValue}" >
                        <CommandBinding Command="{Binding SelectionChangedCommand}"/>
                    </ComboBox>

Comment: Hi rmjoia, this is not a duplicate of the link you have posted. Please do not infer.

Comment: Hi Bojie, I am suppose to strictly follow MVVM.

Comment: @ReizTroyDurante You should edit your question to include relevant code, not throw it somewhere in comments.

Comment: go for interactions

Comment: Thanks everyone! I already found the root cause. The reason for the error is Ive referenced a wrong version of Sytem.Windos.Interactivity(4.5) which is incompatible with the MahApps(4.0) version I am using.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Add Reference to System.Windows.Interactivity as shown below 
   [image]
2. Then in Windows.xaml add below line . This will add reference to XAML

   ```
   xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
   ```

and your XAML will be like as given below 
[image]

And your Combobox XAML be like : -

```
<ComboBox Name="myComboBox" SelectedValuePath="Content">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding YourCommandName}" 
             CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=myComboBox, 
              Path=SelectedValue}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
     </i:Interaction.Triggers>
     <ComboBoxItem Content="ItemOne" />
     <ComboBoxItem Content="ItemTwo" />
     <ComboBoxItem Content="ItemThree" />
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: I got error: {"Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Interactivity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)":"System.Windows.Interactivity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"}

Comment: You have to  add as reference

Comment: @ReizTroyDurante I added the code reference

Comment: Thanks Ramankingdom! I already found the root cause. The reason for the error is Ive referenced a wrong version of Sytem.Windos.Interactivity(4.5) which is incompatible with the MahApps(4.0) version I am using.

Comment: can you please mark as answer.