# How to eject the class fields from control?

Tags: c#, itemssource

I have my own user control. This control's code:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Login}" Margin="0,18,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Address}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
</StackPanel>
</Border>
<Button Name="watchBut" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource RoundButtonTemplate}" Margin="5,0,5,5" FontSize="15" Content="Watch" Click="watchBut_Click"/>
```

I created it to make a grid of these controls, it looks like this:

[image]

This grid is ItemsControl. Its code:

```
<ItemsControl Name="items" Margin="5,-5,5,5" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:MyControl />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

In the code this ItemsControl is binded to List of my class objects. My class:

```
class MyItem
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string Login { set; get; }
    public string Address { set; get; }

    public MyItem(int Id, string Login, string Address)
    {
        this.Id = Id;
        this.Login = Login;
        this.Address = Address;
    }
}
```

How it is populated:

```
List<MyItem> Computers = new List<MyItem>
{
    new MyItem(0,"08739","10.3.0.9"),
    new MyItem(1,"08813","10.3.0.11"),
    new MyItem(2,"09832","10.3.0.14"),
    new MyItem(3,"09854","10.3.0.12"),
    new MyItem(4,"09984","10.3.0.17"),
    new MyItem(5,"proskurin","10.3.0.1"),
    new MyItem(6,"karavaev","10.3.0.2"),
    new MyItem(7,"deba","10.3.0.13")
};
items.ItemsSource = Computers;
```

I want to get MyItem class object information (for example, "09984", "10.3.0.17") by clicking the button "Watch" under this rectangle. Something like this:

Comment: *"I want to get MyItem class object information"* -- get it where and do what with it? What button? What rectangle? What does "eject" mean to you?

Comment: I want to get it in the code (.cs).  
Open the screenshot. There is a grid of controls. One control contains gray rectangle with two TextBlocks (08739, 10.3.0.9) and a Button with text "Watch" below it.  
I have a list of MyItem class (string Login, string Address) objects called Computers. ("items" is a name of ItemsControl):  
_items.ItemsSource = Computers;_   
  
So by clicking the button I want to get MyItem class object

Comment: What button? What rectangle? What does "eject" mean to you? I'm not asking you to reiterate everything you already said in your question.

Comment: "Watch" button. Gray rectangle, containing two strings. It means to me to get MyItem object from the UserControl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void watchBut_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var myItem = ((Button)sender).DataContext as MyItem;

    //  Do stuff
}
```

You could instead [give MyItem a property that returns a Command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1468830/424129) and send the datacontext as the command parameter:

```
<Button 
    Name="watchBut" 
    Grid.Row="1" 
    Style="{StaticResource RoundButtonTemplate}" 
    Margin="5,0,5,5" 
    FontSize="15" 
    Content="Watch" 
    Command="{Binding WatchCommand}"
    CommandParameter="{Binding}"
    />
```

A binding without a Path just binds the DataContext itself (the instance of `MyItem` in this case) to the property. That's the "better", more pure-MVVM solution, but you're not doing very pure MVVM here and event handlers aren't a mortal sin.

Comment: @Shaamaan OP doesn't bind to ItemsSource, but he does have a DataTemplate that binds to properties of `MyItem`.