# How to write data into datagrid and charge property?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I have property `ObservableCollection` in my `ViewModel` and in `View` I want to charge that property throw the DataGrid. I want to do that with button. Can anybody Help me? My property has Name and Value and both of them are strings.

```
public ObservableCollection<Parameter> EnviromentVariables
{
    get;
}
```

XAML code:

```
<GroupBox Header="Enviroment Variables" Width="250" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding EnviromentVariables}"  CanUserAddRows="True" Height="150" IsReadOnly="False" Margin="10">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Content="+" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</GroupBox>
```

Comment: What you want to do ? You have already set your `ItemsSource` to your `ObservableCollection` . Please try to clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

you could bind the button click command with a ICommand into your VM.

there is another post wiht more details:
[WPF ICommand MVVM implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468791/wpf-icommand-mvvm-implementation)