# Problem with binding button to function in mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm trying to bind a button to a function which is in an other project **(MVVM)**.
My XML-Code **(View)** looks like this:

```
<Button Click="{Binding PressMe}">Press Me!</Button>
```

and my **ViewModel-Code** like this:

```
    public void PressMe()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ouch!");
    }
```

When I try to run the program the error *"InvalidCastException: The Object of the type "System.Reflection.RuntimeEventInfo" couldn't be converted to the type "System.Reflection.MethodInfo"*. Any ideas?

Thanks for any reply

Comment: Click is supposed to be wired to an event handler in the code-behind file. You cannot bind to an event. You can bind to the `Command` property to a public `ICommand` source property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using MVVM as you assum, then you should use commands instead of click

```
<Button Command="{Binding Path=PressMe}" />

private ICommand _pressMe;

public ICommand PressMe
{
    get
    {
        if (_pressMe== null)
        {
            _pressMe= new RelayCommand(
                param => this.PressMeObject(), 
                param => this.CanPress()
            );
        }
        return _pressMe;
    }
}


private void PressMeObject()
{
    // Press me logic hier
}

private bool CanPress()
{
    // Verify command can be executed here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Click is an event so you need code behind to make it work.

While I will suggest:

1. Replacing the "click" attribute with "Command".
2. Implement your Relay command or other third party libraries ( Eg: [MVVM Light toolkit](http://www.mvvmlight.net/) ).

Also [ICommand MVVM implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468791/icommand-mvvm-implementation/1468830#1468830) would help.