# ICommand HasErrors Not Bubbling Up to Parent

Tags: c#, wpf, error-handling

I have implemented asynchronous validation as per [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20190209072409/http://burnaftercoding.com/post/asynchronous-validation-with-wpf-4-5/).

I have used data annotations in both my `Organization` class and my `Address` class.  Organization has an `OrgnizationName` property (string) Address property.  The relevant bits are:

**Address.cs**

```
        private string city;
        [Required]
        public string City
        {
            get { return this.city; }
            set
            {
                if (this.city != value)
                {
                    this.city = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("City");
                }
            }
        }
// Other Address bits...
```

**Organization.cs**

```
        private string organizationName;
        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        [Display(Name = "Organization")]
        public string OrganizationName
        {
            get { return this.organizationName; }
            set
            {
                if (this.organizationName != value)
                {
                    this.organizationName = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("OrganizationName");
                }
            }
        }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Address")]
        public Address Address { get; set; } = new Address();
// Other Organization bits...
```

My VM is:

**OrganizationVM.cs**

```
    public class OrganizationDetailsVM : ValidatableModel
    {
        public Organization Organization { get; set; }

        public OrganizationDetailsVM (Organization inputOrganization)
        {
            Organization = inputOrganization;
            // other bits  here...
        }

        public Command SaveCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new Command(() =>
                {
                    Debug.Print("Saving Organization...");

                    try
                    {
                        if (Organization.OrganizationID == 0)
                            Organization.AddOrganization();
                        else
                            Organization.UpdateOrganization();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        EventHandler<FailureEventArgs> h = Failure;
                        FailureEventArgs args = new FailureEventArgs { ErrorMessage = ex.ToString() };

                        h?.Invoke(this, args);
                    }                       
                }, () =>
                {
                    return !HasErrors  &&  !Organization.HasErrors  &&  !Organization.Address.HasErrors;
                });
            }
        }
// More bits...
```

The piece that has me stymied is this:

```
    return !HasErrors  &&  !Organization.HasErrors  &&  !Organization.Address.HasErrors;
```

If I simply use this:

```
    return !HasErrors
```

... it does not pick up the errors of the child properties.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Pleas show the `Command` class

Comment: @aepot I used the solution at the bottom of this post:

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468791/icommand-mvvm-implementation)