# Does MVVM pattern in WPF allow to manage click event in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, design-patterns, mvvm, desktop-application

How do events management work in WPF using MVVM pattern? Should i really avoid using a direct event management?
EXAMPLE: is building a view like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Button Click="GO_Button_Click" Content="Go" Margin="39,143,503,250"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="outputFolder" Margin="321,182,35,211" Text="{Binding outputFolderPath}"/>
</Grid>
```

having a viewmodel like this:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace FirstWpfApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region variables
        public string outputFolderPath { get; set; }
        #endregion

        #region events
        private void GO_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            outputFolderPath = "Some data";
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(outputFolderPath)));
        }

        #endregion

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

Wouldn't i have a better implementation of MVVM pattern avoiding to call "GO_Button_Click"  method from view?

Answer (score 1):

Your XAML should like below,

```
<Button Command="{Binding Button1Command}" Content="GO"/>
```

And the code in MainWindow.xaml.cs. Here MainVM is the name of the ViewModel.

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window {
        MainVM _vm;
        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
            _vm = new MainVM(); //Also you handle it by Singleton instance
            base.DataContext = _vm;
        } 
    }
```

Now let see how the MainVM look like,

```
    public class MainVM : INotifyPropertyChanged {
        public DelegateCommand Button1Command { get; set; }
        public MainVM() {
            Button1Command = new DelegateCommand(onButton1Command);
        }
        private void onButton1Command(object obj) {
            //Your Code when Go button press
        }
        

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected Action<PropertyChangedEventArgs> RaisePropertyChanged() {
            return args => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, args);
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Here is the DelegateCommand class that implement the ICommand interface,

```
public class DelegateCommand : ICommand {
        private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;
        private readonly Action<object> _execute;

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute)
            : this(execute, null) {
        }

        public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute,
                       Predicate<object> canExecute) {
            _execute = execute;
            _canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter) {
            if (_canExecute == null) {
                return true;
            }

            return _canExecute(parameter);
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter) {
            _execute(parameter);
        }

        public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged() {
            CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

button has 'Command' Property, so you can binds it with a class which implement 'ICommand' interface. please check following docs. [ICommand MVVM implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468791/icommand-mvvm-implementation).

and Plus, It seems like you use MainWindow as a `DataContext`, itself. this is not a MVVM ways. I think this way is just WPF binding practices. If you want to achieve MVVM part, first you should make `ViewModel` of window that represent an application domain knowledge and set `DataContext` of MainWindow to the `ViewModel`